# I can't remove the class I gave to the container

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, addeventlistener

I tried to add a class to the text container that I click on and then the class assigns a color to the text I click on.  the problem is when i click the same text twice, the class won't be removed. Any solution for this case?

PLEASE DON'T CHANGE WHERE THE CLASS IS

```js
const contain = document.querySelector('.contain');
const inConts = document.querySelectorAll('.in-cont');

contain.addEventListener('click', e => {
  for (inCont of inConts) {
    inCont.classList.remove('red');
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains('txt')) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.in-cont.red .txt {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing the `red` class, check whether `inCont` contains the event target:

```js
const contain = document.querySelector('.contain');
const inConts = document.querySelectorAll('.in-cont');

contain.addEventListener('click', e => {
  for (inCont of inConts) {
    if (!inCont.contains(e.target)) {
      inCont.classList.remove('red');
    }
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains('txt')) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.in-cont.red .txt {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But i don't understand   !inCont.contains(e.target)

Comment: doesn't contains just check if a class exists or not?

Comment: @ShaefulAmin `contains` checks whether the element is a child of the element, or is the element itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily toggle the class `red` using [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) as:

> `closest` searches the DOM upwards for an element that matches the
> selector. This search includes the element itself.

```
element.closest(selector)
```

> If it finds an element that matches the selector, it returns the
> element. If it doesn’t find any elements, it returns `null`

```js
const contain = document.querySelector('.contain');
const inConts = document.querySelectorAll('.in-cont');

contain.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest("div.contain")) {
    e.target.closest("div.in-cont").classList.toggle("red")
  }
});
```

```css
.in-cont.red .txt {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="in-cont">
    <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```